# Get Distinct value from a list in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a DB column that has a comma delimited list:

```
VALUES          ID
--------------------
1,11,32          A
11,12,28         B
1                C
32,12,1          D
```

When I run my SQL statement, in my `WHERE` clause I have tried `IN`, `CONTAINS` and `LIKE` with varying degrees of errors and success, but none offer an exact return of what I need.

What I need is a where clause that if I'm looking for all IDs with vale of '1' (NOT the number) in the list.

**Example of problem:**

`WHERE` values like (1)

This will return A,B,C,D because 1 is included in the value (11). I would expect IDs (A,C,D).

`WHERE` values like (2)

This will return A,B,D because 2 is included in the value (32,28,12). I would expect zeros records.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The previous developer did this so I was following suite, however, I do have the ability to change it. So I think  I will. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will begin my answer by quoting the spot-on comment given by @Jarlh above:

> Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

That being said, if you're really stuck with this design, you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ',' + [VALUES] + ',' LIKE '%,1,%';
```

The trick here is convert every `VALUES` into something looking like:

```
,11,12,28,
```

Then, we can search for a target number with comma delimiters on both sides.  Since we placed commas at both ends, then every number in the CSV list is now guaranteed to have commas around it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I appreciate the help. I do have the opportunity to change the DB structure, so I think I will.

Comment: @DavidJacobson If you have every CSV value on a separate row, life gets much easier.  So, for example, the `A`, `B`, and `D` rows each have 3 CSV values, so you would instead end up with nine records.

Comment: Also note you'll always be forced to do a full table scan every time you run the query, so perf might be an issue if the table is large.  Could be an interesting opportunity to use a materialized view (I think SQL Server calls them indexed views)

Comment: should add a replace (values,' ','')  to make sure there's no space like ', 11 , '

Comment: @MikeChristensen I don't see how an indexed view will help here, unless you mean an indexed view that explodes all the CSV values into normalized columns (which the OP is already planning to do for the base table anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with such a poor data model, I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from string_split(t.values, ',') s
              where s.value = 1
             );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is the string_split syntax have version limitations? We are using MSSQL 2012.

Comment: @DavidJacobson . . . `string_split()` was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly i echo what jarlh and Tim says. relational model is not the right place to store comma delimited strings in table.

Here is an approach, that can likely use an index if there is one on column x

```
select distinct x
  from t
 cross apply string_split(t.x,',')
where value=1 /*out here you may parameterize, and also could make use of an index each if there is one in value*/ 

+---------+
|    x    |
+---------+
|       1 |
| 1,11,32 |
| 32,12,1 |
+---------+
```

working example
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9b3084f52b0f42ffd17d90427016999

--SQL Server older versions

```
with data
 as (
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') as val
      ,y
      ,x
           FROM (
                 SELECT x1 = CAST('<t>' + 
                             REPLACE(x , ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
                        ,y 
                        ,x
                   FROM t
                ) a
     CROSS APPLY x1.nodes('/t') t(c)
     )
select x,y
  from data

+---------+
|    x    |
+---------+
|       1 |
| 1,11,32 |
| 32,12,1 |
+---------+
```

working example
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=011a096bbdd759ea5fe3aa74b08bc895

Comment: Doesn't work on 2012, though. Earliest version fiddle currently supports is 2014, and here's what happens there: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b9b3084f52b0f42ffd17d90427016999 The OP is going to fix the design, because that's the real problem, in case you were tempted to produce a custom UDF.

Comment: The best way is to fix the design, and i have said that. However if you are stuck with the design, my query and Gordon query can potentially make use of an index if available. For earlier versions there are options that does the same thing as string_split

Comment: That's my point, the OP is not stuck with the design, they've already said they are going to fix it. So a solution that handles the data in a shape it won't stay in, that won't work on their version, isn't valuable (and there are hundreds of Q & A already to solve that case anyway, for those that _are_ stuck in a bad design, regardless of version).

Comment: When i wrote the answer there was no mention of the sql-server version,that it was 2012. My point is that a query that hard-parses each time and has to do a full scan, might not be the most optimal version. (see comment by Mike Christensen)

Comment: /shrug ok. You answered a question that has since changed (because I asked the OP to clarify their version so people don't assume they can use modern features). That's not your fault, but your answer should change too (or disappear), IMHO. Using a custom UDF on the existing design will still require a full scan, and maybe worse if a multi-statement TVF is chosen from search results, so it does not solve the problem any more optimally than the selected answer anyway.

Comment: fair enough, i have updated. Also  its good to understand the point about not using indexes and full table scan in the other answer

Comment: Yes, this XML approach is one way to split strings, but it doesn’t help this user because they’ve already committed to fixing the bad design, and even if it did help them, it’s not the most efficient solution even on this page. If you're going to nitpick someone else's approach because it will be slow without a supporting index, you should make sure [your solution isn’t 4X as slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzCl5.png) (without an index) or even has the opportunity to add an index that would help make it faster (what index would that be, exactly? How can you avoid a scan with this solution?).

Comment: Sorry I’m biased / passionate, but I’ve written [just](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) [a](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up) [few](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) [things](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat) [about](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) splitting strings, and I'm familiar with the worst performers at scale.

Comment: thanks for that Aaron, I do not have access to sql server to try out the statistics, shrug. However could you run both query three times each, and show the client statistics tab.

Comment: I admit the index, was a wrong assumption from my side. I had mistakenly thought about the scenario of "in list" equivalent in oracle, where the approach of ','||variable||',' precludes an index. Here is a link https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/varying-in-lists.html#114928107186728370. I am aware we cannot compare oracle and sql server just like that.

Comment: I had to make a couple of changes to support your request (1) select into something instead of try to return all that data to SSMS and (2) reduce the number of rows to 100K and 500K (because 5MM took over my machine's CPU) to compare. Here are the results ([100K rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHp4r.png) and [500K rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkAjU.png)). You can make up your own tests, too (but if you can't even test your solution on SQL Server...). I'm not making it up; I've seen it over and over again: XML is slower (and it's needlessly complex code for this specific scenario to boot).